# Backup online iMessage repository

Tags: ios, icloud, messages

Is there a way to download/export iMessage history somewhere? If I deleted messages on a local device, is it also removed online on iCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) or a similar application to download your iMessage database to your Mac.

iMessage data is not stored in iCloud, not even as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your iMessage history, use Baskup, an OS X application that backs up all your iMessages from your Macbook

https://peterkaminski09.github.io/baskup